# Sequelize: unable to delete a table entry due to a foreign key constraint issue

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am building a simple API to relearn how to use the sequelize ORM and am running into an issue with foreign key constraints. I have a many to many relationship between ThingsToDoLists and ThingsToDoListTags through ThingsToDoListTagJoins. This is what the models look like for each file:

thingstodolist.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ThingsToDoList = sequelize.define('ThingsToDoList', {
    listName: DataTypes.STRING(128),
    listDescription: DataTypes.STRING(128),
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});
  ThingsToDoList.associate = function(models) {
    
    ThingsToDoList.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "userId",
    })
    
    ThingsToDoList.belongsToMany(
      models.ThingsToDo,
      {
        through:"ThingsToDoTOThingsToDoListJoins",
        otherKey: "thingToDoId",
        foreignKey: "thingToDoListId"
      }
    )

    ThingsToDoList.belongsToMany(
      models.ThingsToDoListTag, 
      {
        through: "ThingsToDoListTagJoins",
        otherKey: "thingsToDoListTagId",
        foreignKey: "thingsToDoListId",
      }
    )
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return ThingsToDoList;
};
```

thingstodotagjoins.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ThingsToDoListTagJoins = sequelize.define('ThingsToDoListTagJoins', {
    thingsToDoListId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    thingsToDoListTagId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  ThingsToDoListTagJoins.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return ThingsToDoListTagJoins;
};
```

thingstodolisttag.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ThingsToDoListTag = sequelize.define('ThingsToDoListTag', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING(128)
  }, {});
  ThingsToDoListTag.associate = function(models) {
    ThingsToDoListTag.belongsToMany(models.ThingsToDoList,
      {
        through: "ThingsToDoListTagJoins",
        otherKey: "thingsToDoListId",
        foreignKey: "thingsToDoListTagId"
      })

    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return ThingsToDoListTag;
};
```

I am trying to delete a ThingToDoList entry and the connection to the ThingToDoListTag, but not delete the ThingToDoListTag itself. When I try to use

```js
await retrievedThingToDoList.destroy()
```

I get an error saying I voilated a foreign key constraint. I did try to use `{"onDelete": "CASCADE", "hooks": true}` and got the same issue. This is the specific error:

```
Executing (default): DELETE FROM "ThingsToDoLists" WHERE "id" = 1
ForeignKeyConstraintError [SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError]: update or delete on table "ThingsToDoLists" violates foreign key constraint "ThingsToDoListTagJoins_thingsToDoListId_fkey" on table "ThingsToDoListTagJoins"
    at Query.formatError (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:295:16)
    at /Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:72:18
    at tryCatcher (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21) {
  parent: error: update or delete on table "ThingsToDoLists" violates foreign key constraint "ThingsToDoListTagJoins_thingsToDoListId_fkey" on table "ThingsToDoListTagJoins"
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/aseefried/Projects/ThingsToDoApp/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 374,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '23503',
    detail: 'Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "ThingsToDoListTagJoins".',
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: 'public',
    table: 'ThingsToDoListTagJoins',
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: 'ThingsToDoListTagJoins_thingsToDoListId_fkey',
    file: 'ri_triggers.c',
    line: '2553',
    routine: 'ri_ReportViolation',
    sql: 'DELETE FROM "ThingsToDoLists" WHERE "id" = 1',
    parameters: undefined
  }
```

Am I missing something in the relationships between the models or am I missing something else?

Comment: How did you create tables in DB?